# Internet Explorer BHO and SSL

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, https, plugins, bho

I've developed IE plugin which adds an icon after each link on pages.
But, If I navigate on https sites then I get the message that IE has restricted.....
If I try to allow the access IE shows that message again.
How can I fix it or where am I wrong ?

Comment: i just want to throw a reminder to you to mark answers to your questions. There is a bunch of reasons why, see the faq  (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and this faq post (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238) on reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The icon has a url for its `src` property. IE will be complaining because you are using regular `http` protocol for that `src` property, while the rest of the page uses `https` - so your content is not coming from a secure site.

To fix it, ensure that the url you use has the same protocol as what the rest of the page is delivered by - so you will need to host your images on an `https` enabled site.

Comment: @cpp - it is not complaining about **where** the icon is coming from (although it may do that too depending on how your IE zones are set up), it is compaining about the **protocol** you are using to retrieve it.